# Url Rewrite with Special Characters - Seo Advice Needed

Tags: codeigniter, seo, url-rewriting, special-characters

I'm using Code Igniter to build a simple website, one thing about Code Igniter its that its pretty easy to do Rewrite Rules. But anyway, that ain't the problem.

But lets consider this situation, in this website most webpage itens, if the name its to be spelled correctly the name as special characters ( á à é è .... mostly used in non English languages) and spaces.

Lets take a look at this url (localhost test)

```
http://localhost:88/Ensino/Frota de Veículos
```

This url as a rewrite rule that relays the user to Class **ensino** and the function **frota_de_veiculos** which it would be the same if we go to:

```
http://localhost:88/ensino/frota_de_veiculos
```

However if you enable source view with Firefox, the source view title will display the url this way:

```
http://localhost:88/Ensino/Frota%20de%20Ve%C3%ADculos
```

Now my question its simple which Url will Search Engines consider in they crawl through the website?

I ask this because i once saw a website with Url rewrite using special characters and spaces, and in Google Search would display weird urls like this one: `http://localhost:88/Ensino/Frota%20de%20Ve%C3%ADculos`

**Note:** Keep in mind that the navigation bar pinpoints to `http://localhost:88/Ensino/Frota de Veículos`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would see "Frota%20de%20Ve%C3%ADculos", since that is the public facing URL and the version is the underscores is only used internally.

URLs cannot include spaces, which have to be represented with %20. Some browsers display literal spaces in the address bar instead of %20 to make them more readable. Similar issues apply to non-ASCII characters.

Comment: ... some browsers convert spaces into '+' instead of '%20'

Comment: Dam. Guess i will have to undo the rewrite rules, remove spaces and accentuation , the last thing i want is google to look at this website like this: Frota%20de%20Ve%C3%ADculos. Thanks for clarification.